# echo selected in chosen select

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown

I am using chosen select drop down to show auto complete drop down. I want to set selected value for edit. I tried following code which works for normal select option but not working for chosen select

```
<select class="chosen-select" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php if(!empty($list))
    {
        foreach($list as $d)
        {
            ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $d->id; ?><?php if($d->id == 2) { echo "selected"; } ?>"><?php echo $d->name; ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting your `selected` inside your `value` attribute, you need to write it after :

```
       <select class="chosen-select" >
              <option value=""></option>
                <?php if(!empty($list)) {
                        foreach($list as $d) {
                ?> 
                    <option value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>"<?php if($d->id == 2) { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo $d->name; ?></option>
              <?php  } } ?>
       </select>
```

Comment: On a side note; this answer is valid HTML 5, if you go below or XHTML its `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 1):

Building on @roberto06's answer, the following should be a bit cleaner to look at.

BTW, you really should consider using a template engine.

```php
<select class="chosen-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php if (!empty($list)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($list as $d): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>" <?php echo ($d->id == 2) ? "selected" : "">
                <?php echo $d->name; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```